# Dataframe to json with Nested Arrays with commas

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I am new to python so I need help with this. I have a dataframe `df` as shown below

```
ID               Aisle            Residence        HomePhone        CellPhone
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1245,3214        A1, A2, A3, A4   Home             NaN              888888888
.........        ...........      ...              .......          .........
```

Expected outcome:

```
{
  {
   "maincolumn": "Zone1",
   "mainvalues": [
    {
      "column": "ID",
      "values": [
        "1245",
        "3214"
      ]
    },
    {
      "column": "Aisle",
      "values": [
        "A1",
        "A2",
        "A3",
        "A4"
      ]
    },
    {
      "column": "Residence",
      "values": [
        "Home"
      ]
    },
    {
      "column": "HomePhone",
      "values": []
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "maincolumn": "Zone2",
   "mainvalues": [
   {
      "column": "CellPhone",
      "values": [
        "888888888"
      ]
    }
   ] 
  }
}
```

So basically, I want to add attributes and assign them to values that are column names, such as `"column":"Aisle"`,`"values":["A1","B1,...]"`

`maincolumn` is set based on the original column number, so if the original column name is a cell phone, it will go to zone 2, otherwise everything else is in zone 1 (as seen in the json above).

`mainvalues` is an array with attributes in it that correspond to every column in the Dataframe

Also, I have a restriction that the column names always change (column1, column2, column3) and the number of columns vary, so I cannot hard code columns when converting from DF to JSON.

Thank you so much I appreciate your help

Comment: What is the original column number that `maincolumn` is based on?

Comment: it is not a column in the DF. It is an added attribute to the json. `maincolumn` could be hard coded

Comment: Ok, but if column names are dynamic, how do you know which column names are in which zone?

Comment: @LuckyZakary Only cell phone is in zone two. So columns that contain the keyword ‘cell’ in them go to zone 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the dataframe and then append it in the format you want.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json

df = pd.DataFrame([[[1245, 3214], ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'], 'Home', np.nan, 8888888888], [[9999, 5555], ['A6', 'A7', 'A8', 'A9'], 'Apartment', np.nan, 2222222222]], columns=['ID', 'Aisle', 'Residence', 'HomePhone', 'CellPhone'])
df.replace({np.nan: None}, inplace=True)
outcome = []

for i, ser in df.iterrows():
    temp_dict = [{"maincolumn": "Zone1", "mainvalues": []}, {"maincolumn": "Zone2", "mainvalues": []}]
    for col_name, values in ser.iteritems():
        if "cell" in col_name.lower():
            temp_dict[1]['mainvalues'].append({'column': col_name, 'values': (lambda x: [v for v in x] if type(x) is list else [x])(values)})
        else:
            temp_dict[0]['mainvalues'].append({'column': col_name, 'values': (lambda x: [v for v in x] if type(x) is list else [x])(values)})
    outcome.extend(temp_dict)

outcome = json.dumps(outcome)
print(outcome)
```